# print command paints green in debug area in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm facing weird issue. The print command in following code paints green area in debug window in xCode. It's random.

Why is it happening? How to fix it?

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completionHandler(nil, error)
        }
        return
    }

    print("############## Data ############################################################")
    if let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) { print(str) }
    print("################################################################################")
}
```

[image: Xcode debug area]

Comment: tested the print code it prints just fine. try changing the Xcode Theme you are using.

Comment: Changing theme didn't help. Never faced this issue before, it just started today.

Comment: try to print when Xcode is not in fullscreen

Answer (score 0):

The fix turn out to be the same age old trick, reboot the system. macOS has been crashing all day today when I use Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Restart did not help me.

Making Xcode go to fullscreen made it disappear, and was able to return back to non-fullscreen with it still not green.

Comment: Try to clean xCode. Update xCode. Reboot again. It's not really a problem. I've never seen this issue again after I reported here.

Comment: As I said above, I fixed it by going to fullscreen then back to non-fullscreen. I assume that just refreshed the view of the debug window.

Comment: May be. not sure what is going on. It's not a big deal as long as it doesn't keep coming back. As I said I've never seen this issue again after I posted here.